# Debian launches Skype when root terminal is opened

Tags: linux, debian, skype

I installed Skype on Debian "Jessie". Now every time I launch the root terminal (or type "su" in normal terminal), Skype will open and often my system will eventually freeze, such that I can only move my mouse. Does anyone know how to prevent Skype from launching? I installed according to: https://wiki.debian.org/skype

Thanks in advance!

Comment: May be try reinstalling the Skype and check whether the issue still continues.

Comment: I tried that already. Problem still there...

Answer (score 0):

check the file .bashrc in the root home:

`$ su`

```
# nano .bashrc
```

it should contain the line

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ /usr/bin/skype

comment out that line by putting # at the beginning or delete the line. save the file. done.

Comment: I think you followed this tutorial: http://linuxg.net/how-to-properly-install-skype-4-3-on-debian-and-derivatives-and-fix-the-crashes/ not the one you linked
I had the same problem.